How to scale 2D coordinates of objects on an image, to match bilinear interp. image scaling?
How to correctly transform the points such that each point is in correspondence with the scaling of the image by the function cv2.resize(..., interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)?
Have an image and 2D point coordinates of some objects on that image. Will scale (bilinear)  that image with Sx (horizontal) and Sy (vertical).
I tried with an example of Sx=7.7 and Sy=5.5 on the corners of a 10x10 (h x w) image, the corners are not transformed into the center of the original pixels. So I wanted point (9,9) to be around (52.25, 73.15).
example coordinates:
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 9.],
       [9., 0.],
       [9., 9.]])

translated to the center Cy, Cx = (10-1)/2, (10-1)/2:
array([[-4.5, -4.5],
       [-4.5,  4.5],
       [ 4.5, -4.5],
       [ 4.5,  4.5]])

applying scaling factors Sx and Sy to the array then translating to the new center:
array[:,0] = array[:,0] * Sy + (Cy*Sy)
array[:,1] = array[:,1] * Sx + (Cx*Sx)

array([[ 0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. , 69.3],
       [49.5,  0. ],
       [49.5, 69.3]])


for scaling in general, that highly depends on the implementation. for opencv's resize(): https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9096 -- feel free to submit a PR for better documentation

Do you want your points to be on the center of the pixel, or the corner of the pixel?

@MarkRansom the center. So if the width is 10 pixels to be scaled to 77, then each old pixel corresponds to 7.7 new pixels, a pixel with component x=9 should map to ~ 73.15

It sounds like you already know your answer then.

You need to add 0.5 to each coordinate before you scale it.
